# How do you directly initialize a char array within a struct without memcpy, strcpy, or {...}?

Tags: c++

Here's an example to clarify what I mean:

```
// A struct with a char array
struct StructA
{
   char value[6];
};

char Initializer[6] = "Hello";

// This works
StructA works = { "Hello" );

// This doesn't work
StructA doesNotWork = { Initializer };

#define MyValue "Hello"
StructA alsoDoesNotWork = { MyValue };
```

Yes, memcpy, strcpy, loops, et. al. can be used to easily accomplish this, but I'd like to just use a direct initialization approach.

I've run into this same issue before and found a solution, but forgot what it was :-(

I'm fairly certain the approach I used last time involved macros in some way.

(Why doesn't the `MyValue` macro expand to `"Hello"` anyways?)

Comment: Your last example will work if you fix the typo; it should be `#define MyValue "Hello"` without the `=`.

Comment: The last one does work

Comment: typo fixed; I'm fairly certain I had the macro defined correctly in code and it still didn't work :( I'll confirm again. thx

Comment: [Works fine here](https://godbolt.org/z/sv4nzr) so you may have had some other mistake in your code.

Comment: Agh, I must have inadvertently used the "=" in the macro earlier...it's been a long day. Apologies for the false flag.

Comment: For completeness: I did not have the equal sign in my macro, but had erroneously left a semi colon AFTER the macro:  #define MyValue "Hello";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you directly initialize a char array within a struct without memcpy, strcpy, or {...}?

You can use one a string literal in a default member initialiser:

```
struct StructA
{
   char value[6] = "Hello";
};
```

If you don't mind using the curly brackets for another object, then you can use that to initialise the another without curlies:

```
constexpr StructA Initializer { "Hello" };
StructA works = Initializer;
```

That said, it's unclear why you are against using curly brackets. Don't worry; they won't bite you.

---

> ```
> #define MyValue "Hello"
> StructA alsoDoesNotWork = { MyValue };
> ```

You've named the variable "alsoDoesNotWork". However, this **does work**. Regardless, I recommend to **not** use a macro.

> (Why doesn't the MyValue macro expand to "Hello" anyways?)

It does.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I'm not against brackets in general, but don't want to enumerate the string char by char as is often suggested (e.g. {'H', 'e', 'l', ...}

Comment: @CharlesT. There's no need to do that just because you use curl brackets. Use a string literal instead. Theres an example of how to do that in your question with the comment `// This works`.

Comment: Any idea why C++ doesn't allow specifying a const char[] variable for the assignment?  (e.g. structA  a = {"Hello"} vs. structA b = {Initializer}; ?

Comment: @CharlesT. Because arrays are not copy-initialisable.

Comment: @CharlesT. A C++ array is really, really stupid. That stupidity made a lot of sense back in the 1970s, you didn't have enough RAM or CPU power to copy arrays willy-nilly, but that history lives on so as to not invalidate older programs and because after 50 years, that's the expected behaviour. Besides, most of the time you still don't want to copy arrays. You can have a lot more fun with a container like `std::array` that has more "normal" value semantics.

Comment: I do love C++ (and the C history it shares). Thanks all for the comments -- much appreciated.